# Using webrtc-58 in Android NDK project - "Undefined reference to CopyOnWriteBuffer" when building with QT

Tags: android, c++, qt, android-ndk, webrtc

I am trying to build a shared library for Android NDK which is referencing libjingle_peerconnection.so built for Android from webrtc-58, but linker errors appearing:

```
MyProject\Libs\webrtc-58\include\webrtc\api\datachannelinterface.h:64: error: undefined reference to 'rtc::CopyOnWriteBuffer::~CopyOnWriteBuffer()'
MyProject\Libs\webrtc-58\include\webrtc\base\copyonwritebuffer.h:48: error: undefined reference to 'rtc::CopyOnWriteBuffer::CopyOnWriteBuffer(unsigned int, unsigned int)'
```

The same output I have building the project on Ubuntu as well as  Windows. When building on Ubuntu, I configured QT Creator to use Android SDK/NDK from webrtc build tools(which were used to build the libjingle_peerconnection

QT Creator 4.4.1 on Qt5.9.2
 webrtc-58 was built on Ubuntu using follwoing configuration

```
gn gen out/Debug/arm-v7 --args='target_os="android" is_component_build=false rtc_include_tests=false target_cpu="arm"'
```

I've dumped the unstripped libjingle_peerconnection.so and noticed that contains CopyOnWriteBuffer class implementation:

```
001b2bbd t void rtc::CopyOnWriteBuffer::AppendData<unsigned char, (void*)0>(unsigned char const*, unsigned int)
000ee055 t rtc::CopyOnWriteBuffer::EnsureCapacity(unsigned int)
000edf51 t rtc::CopyOnWriteBuffer::CloneDataIfReferenced(unsigned int)
000fafd9 t char* rtc::CopyOnWriteBuffer::data<char, (void*)0>()
000fae61 t unsigned char* rtc::CopyOnWriteBuffer::data<unsigned char, (void*)0>()
000eddcd t rtc::CopyOnWriteBuffer::Clear()
00092cd1 t void rtc::CopyOnWriteBuffer::SetData<char, (void*)0>(char const*, unsigned int)
00092cd1 t void rtc::CopyOnWriteBuffer::SetData<unsigned char, (void*)0>(unsigned char const*, unsigned int)
000edb4d t rtc::CopyOnWriteBuffer::SetSize(unsigned int)
000fad19 t rtc::CopyOnWriteBuffer::operator=(rtc::CopyOnWriteBuffer&&)
000ed6f1 t rtc::CopyOnWriteBuffer::CopyOnWriteBuffer(unsigned int)
000ed7d9 t rtc::CopyOnWriteBuffer::CopyOnWriteBuffer(unsigned int, unsigned int)
000ed6e1 t rtc::CopyOnWriteBuffer::CopyOnWriteBuffer(rtc::CopyOnWriteBuffer&&)
0003462f t rtc::CopyOnWriteBuffer::CopyOnWriteBuffer(rtc::CopyOnWriteBuffer const&)
0002f1f7 t rtc::CopyOnWriteBuffer::CopyOnWriteBuffer()
000faa35 t rtc::CopyOnWriteBuffer::CopyOnWriteBuffer<char, (void*)0>(char const*, unsigned int)
000ed6f1 t rtc::CopyOnWriteBuffer::CopyOnWriteBuffer(unsigned int)
000ed7d9 t rtc::CopyOnWriteBuffer::CopyOnWriteBuffer(unsigned int, unsigned int)
000ed6e1 t rtc::CopyOnWriteBuffer::CopyOnWriteBuffer(rtc::CopyOnWriteBuffer&&)
0003462f t rtc::CopyOnWriteBuffer::CopyOnWriteBuffer(rtc::CopyOnWriteBuffer const&)
0002f1f7 t rtc::CopyOnWriteBuffer::CopyOnWriteBuffer()
000faa35 t rtc::CopyOnWriteBuffer::CopyOnWriteBuffer<char, (void*)0>(char const*, unsigned int)
0003452d t rtc::CopyOnWriteBuffer::~CopyOnWriteBuffer()
0003452d t rtc::CopyOnWriteBuffer::~CopyOnWriteBuffer()
```

Content of the MYPROJECT_Core.Pro

```
QT  += core xml
QT  -= gui

TARGET = MYPROJECT_Core
TEMPLATE = lib

DEFINES += MYPROJECT_CORE_LIBRARY

DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS
DEFINES += NOMINMAX
DEFINES += ENABLE_RTC_EVENT_LOG


QMAKE_CFLAGS_WARN_ON -= -Wall
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_WARN_ON -= -Wall
CONFIG += warn_off

android {
    CONFIG += c++11
    QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11

    DEFINES += NDEBUG=1
    DEFINES += WEBRTC_POSIX
    DEFINES += WEBRTC_ANDROID

    LIBS += -L$$PWD/../Libs/webrtc-58/lib/android/armeabi-v7a/jni/armeabi-v7a -ljingle_peerconnection_so
    INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../Libs/webrtc-58/include
    DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../Libs/webrtc-58/include
} 


SOURCES += \
    main.cpp \
```

Comment: Do you only have the `main.cpp` source file?

Comment: **libjingle_peerconnection_so.so** does not export C++ classes. It only exposes JNI functions that are expected to be called from Java. If your **main.cpp** uses any WebRTC classes, you must use **libjingle_peerconnection.a**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My colleague solved this problem today.
He replaced libjingle_peerconnection.so with another libraries from webrtc build output

```
obj/webrtc/api/libjingle_peerconnection_api.a
ob/webrtc/base/librtc_base_approved.a
```

Also there was a compatibility problem with QT Android Kit and webrtc build system, so Android Kit is building with gnustl, while webrtc was build with libc++, so he included libc++_shared.so from Android NDK bundle.
Entire Pro file will look like this

```
QT       -= gui

TARGET = WebRtcDependantLib
TEMPLATE = lib

#CONFIG += c++11
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions
DEFINES += MY_TEST_LIBRARY

android {
    DEFINES += WEBRTC_POSIX
    DEFINES += WEBRTC_ANDROID


    DEFINES += NDEBUG

    WEBRTC = /home/user/Dev/src  #WEBRTC-M58 sources directory
    WEBRTCBUILD = $$WEBRTC/out/Debug/arm-v7/obj
    #android NDK bundled by webrtc build system
    WEBRTCNDK = $$WEBRTC/third_party/android_tools/ndk

    LIBS += -Wl,--start-group
    LIBS += $$WEBRTCBUILD/webrtc/api/libjingle_peerconnection_api.a
    LIBS += $$WEBRTCBUILD/webrtc/base/librtc_base_approved.a
    LIBS += -Wl,--end-group

    LIBS += $$WEBRTCNDK/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libs/armeabi-v7a/libc++_shared.so 

    INCLUDEPATH += $$WEBRTC
    DEPENDPATH += $$WEBRTC
}
SOURCES += \
        main.cpp
```

Comment: Mixing stl runtimes in one project is very dangerous, and may cause crashes that are hard to analyze. Can't you get rod of gnustl?

Comment: @AlexCohn , you were right. After compiling the project, we've got very unstable application with random crashes. Finally we had to build QT with clang tool-chain, to get the webrtc integrated in QT project.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about WebRTC-58, but I know that WebRTC 60 has a script to build the Android libs for you.  From the src/ directory, just run

```
python tools_webrtc/android/build_aar.py
```

This will configured everything for you, build for x86, x86_64, arm, and arm64, and combine them into libwebrtc.aar which you can add to your android project.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but I am building android NDK application and seems unable to refer the aar lib from C++ code without reffering .h files